# Application stops before showing anything

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, google-console-developer

I've got some problems, only one for now.

I deploy my application to Google Play about 2 months ago, and yesterday I received an email relating the app does not open in a device and it break before open, showing on the screen "Unfortunately, (?) Has stopped". It runs normaly in another device, but not in the "J3 (2016) android version 5.11's user".

I opened the Google Play Console, and looked for answers in ANR's menu. I found this:

```
**java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:**
at md5846bd09d5a4e74db0c2de01aa9d1e1cf.MainActivity.n_onCreate (Native Method)
at md5846bd09d5a4e74db0c2de01aa9d1e1cf.MainActivity.onCreate (MainActivity.java:30)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:6609)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1134)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3113)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3275)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000 (ActivityThread.java:218)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1744)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:145)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7007)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1404)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

I'll try to reproduce this error via android emulator.
Does anybody seen this before, know how to solve and can help me?

Thank you guys.

Comment: Does it crash in your emulator?

Comment: what do you mean by other devices ? pyhsical or emulator ? and can you check your application's minor version of android ?

Comment: Well, the error says the method is not available which means it is an API unavailable in v5.1

Comment: I tried to emulate my app by Android Emulator with Lollipop 5.1.1, and I've got the same error. The debugger return me this message: "Java.Lang.LinkageError: ".

Comment: I mean a pyshical device @Batuhan

Comment: I think your application doesn't support under android 6 versions , Can you check your app's minor target of android version ? You can find it in project settings

Comment: @G.hakim, but which API? How can I verify which API is this?

Comment: @Batuhan, I opened the projects properties, and the Minimum Android Version is 5.0

Comment: Is this a Xamarin Forms app or a Xamarin Android app? If it is a Forms app and there nothing more to the above error like a little context, Literally no one would know what is not working

Comment: @G.hakim It is a Xamarin Forms Application but I have only the Android Project and the Cross Platform Project.

Comment: @G.hakim This application uses the Zxing, to read QR Codes (we've some Asynchronous Methods!), and a Handler Protocol to load the user's information inside the aplication through an URI, using a schema

Comment: You do not need to have an android emulator just any device below 5.1 would usually cause this because `NoSuchMethod` usually signifies `deprecation` or no `backward compatibility.`

Comment: After some tests here, I saw that the application only runs from Android 6.0 to up, and this error repeats in lowest versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found where the error occours, thank God! After a long code analysis day, I found my error, and it is related with permission request, and works like that:

-From Android 6.0 to up, the applications need to ask permission to use some functionalities from the device (I did this structure). But what happens is that, below to 6.0, needn't to request permission, and then I had a conflict.

So, I did a conditional structure to verify the device's Android Version, and depending of its version, will or not request permissions.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are doing something in the native code of your app which is not supported on Android 5. From the comments it appears you can reproduce this in an emulator. So the next step to find out what is breaking is to look at your native code, or even use native code debugging in your emulator to find out whatr it failing.

There are some docs on [native code debugging in Androud Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug) here.

Comment: I developed this application in Xamarin, on Visual Studio. With Android Studio debugger, can I debug the application that runs in my emulator? It is correct? Looks a little confuse. How can I do it?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know much about Xamarin. Microsoft appear to have some docs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/debugging/debug-on-emulator?tabs=windows but I've never tried it

Comment: Don't be sorry, its OK. Thank you for your help. I read some lines from this docs, but in Xamarin it is only possible to debug C#, not Native. By the way, I noticed that this application only runs from 6.0 to up, so I'll change my Android Manifest's Minimum Version to 6.0.